# jquery plugins like masonry,Carousel etc not working inside Pjax page

Tags: php, pjax

I am using `pjax` for my website. some `JQuery` plugin could not initiate inside pjax page. With out pjax its working fine.
This is my pjax code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var direction = "right";
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).pjax('a', '#main');
        $(document).on('pjax:start', function() {
            console.log("pjax started");
            $(this).addClass('loading');
        });
        $(document).on('pjax:end', function() {
            console.log("pjax ended");
            $(this).removeClass('loading');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the you have tried yet.

Comment: pls check my updated question